# how to add text to output

Tags: python

Idk if I'm overthinking this or just really tired, but I was trying to figure out the best way to add text to this function

```
print(os.path.getsize(os.path.join('/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/dogs', 'dogs.jpg')), 'bytes')
```

this is the results

```
59520 bytes
```

but I need

```
dogs.jpg: 5920 bytes
```

Comment: print(os.path.getsize('dogs.jpg', os.path.join('/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/dogs', 'dogs.jpg')), 'bytes')

Comment: You have appended text. You can prepend it in the same way: `print("dogs.jpg:",...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get the size in bytes aond convert it to a string:

```
path_name = '/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/dogs'
file_name = 'dogs.jpg'
size_string = str(os.path.getsize(os.path.join(path_name, file_name)))
```

Then concatenate it with the desired text:

```
output_text = file_name + ': ' + size_string + ' bytes'
print(output_text)
```

Alternatively, you could use an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python) instead, with the same result:

```
output_text = f"{file_name}: {size_string} bytes"
print(output_text)
```

You could do everything on one or two lines like the other answers, but it's always better to be clearer rather than compact, there's no need to sacrifice readability to make code as small as possible:

```
file_name = "dogs.jpg"
print(f"{file_name}: {str(os.path.getsize(os.path.join('/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/dogs', file_name)))} bytes")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am being dumb but can you do this:

```
print('dogs jpg:', os.path.getsize(os.path.join('/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/dogs', 'dogs.jpg')), 'bytes')
```